# ContextErrorException after generating a bundle in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have this problem for days now... I just do a fresh install on syfmony but after i create a bundle from symfony console i get this error from the webpage...

```
ContextErrorException: Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(/srv/www/backend.tacon.eu/web) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/clients/client1/web5/web:/var/www/clients/client1/web5/private:/var/www/clients/client1/web5/tmp:/var/www/backend.tacon.eu/web:/srv/www/backend.tacon.eu/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin) in /var/www/clients/client1/web5/web/back/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Process/ExecutableFinder.php line 59
```

I don't know why is this happening. This is not my first symfony project and this never happens. Also on the same server i have various symfony projects.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12772244/1607098)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem after refresh install symfony using composer.
I have solved this issue by editing php configuration file (**php.ini**).

Set the **open_basedir** option to **null**.

More about [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

Answer (score 1):

From ISPConfig:
WebSites-> Your Site -> Options -> PHP open_basedir -> 
Add ***:/srv/www/backend.tacon.eu/web*** at the end of line

Answer (score 0):

if you face this error on live server then you can solve this problem like this-

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
// wrap the default AppKernel with the AppCache one

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

in line    `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);` you may change it `"prod"` or `"dev"` and it's value like `true or false`;