# Symfony / ISPConfig: open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to setup a Symfony installation for the first time on my Ubuntu server with ISPConfig to do some testing. But without any luck until now.

First I encountered a error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException in .../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/Exception/FlattenException.php on line 25.
```

I found out that it was caused by a problem in the latest Symfony composer installation (not sure what exactly caused it). I resolved it by downloading the Symfony library trough Github and overwriting the one that was installed by composer. Both version 2.6.

But now I get the following error:

```
ContextErrorException in ExecutableFinder.php line 59:
Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(/srv/www/symfony.mysite.nl/symfony) is not within the allowed path(s): 
(/var/www/clients/client1/web6/symfony:/var/www/clients/client1/web6/private:/var/www/clients/client1/web6/tmp:/var/www/symfony.mysite.nl/symfony:/srv/www/symfony.mysite.nl/symfony:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin)
```

In my search for a solution I found [ContextErrorException after generating a bundle in Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24995000/contexterrorexception-after-generating-a-bundle-in-symfony) but the answers don't work for me. The path /srv/www/symfony.mysite.nl/symfony is already in the ISPConfig setup of my site at WebSites-> Your Site -> Options -> PHP open_basedir. And even setting "open_basedir = null" in WebSites-> Your Site -> Options -> Custom php.ini settings wil do nothing (I think that it isn't a good idea btw to disable it but I tried).

I tried to install older versions of Symfony but I had the same problems.

Comment: Comment out the open basedir in php.ini. "null" is not available in configs and is parsed as a string.

Comment: In the used php.ini file I can find only one mentioning of the open_basedir: open_basedir = null. This is what I put in config of ISPConfig.

Comment: PHP info shows the following list strangely enough: /var/www/clients/client1/web6/symfony:/var/www/clients/client1/web6/private:/var/www/clients/client1/web6/tmp:/var/www/symfony.mysite.nl/symfony:/srv/www/symfony.mysite.nl/symfony:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin

Comment: Then you are loading a different php.ini configuration

Comment: How can I find out if that's true? Php info states: Loaded Configuration File /var/www/conf/web6_symfony/php.ini

Comment: Put `open_basedir = ` in `/var/www/conf/web6_symfony/php.ini`

Comment: @M4RT13N do you answer your question because i'm facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

You are using the config wrong, `NULL` is not ment to be literally written, use empty value or comment out the whole line using `;`.

```
; open_basedir, if set, limits all file operations to the defined directory
; and below.  This directive makes most sense if used in a per-directory
; or per-virtualhost web server configuration file. This directive is
; *NOT* affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.
; http://php.net/open-basedir
;open_basedir =
```

Comment: I tried to use the empty one without any effect. I can't try to comment it out because I can't find the open_basedir to begin with. I still think the error is strange because the path / file it complains about is in the list of allowed paths.